# Configure a Maven Project

Tags: java, maven

I'm configuring a maven project on eclipse.
I have added struts and hibernate dependencies. When I run my project, I got this error.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext.getThreadContextMap()Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/spi/ReadOnlyThreadContextMap;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need to Add the log4j api to the same version of your log4j in struts.

Like This

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>###Your Version Here ####</version>
</dependency>
```